# In Java, how to find and display a String element in an array based on the location of specific letters in the element?

Tags: java, arrays, string

To explain my problem I am going to give you a scenario:
A user is playing an online pictionary game. Someone else is drawing a picture on the screen. The goal is to be the first person to guess what word the picture represents. The user knows that it is a 3-letter word because on the screen there are three spaces `(_ _ _)`. After 15 seconds, a letter pops up so it now looks like this:
`(_ a _)`.

Here is the issue: I have my program set to where if the user types in the letter *"a"*, all words that are three letters AND have the letter *"a"* in it will appear. However, I want the user to be able to specify which space the letter is in.

Here are all of the possible 3-letter words:

```
String[] lettersThree = {"axe","bow","car","eye","fat","pig","sun"};
```

Right now, if the user types in "a", these words will be printed out: axe, car, fat.

However, in the example, the user knows that "a" is the 2nd letter. I want the print out to only be "car" and "fat" - I do not want "axe" included because the "a" is in the wrong spot.

How can I accomplish this? I have tried looking this up many times but I cannot find any question/answer that has to do with finding specific letters in String elements in arrays. I have only found explanations of how to sort arrays in ascending/descending order and how to find the index of elements. My apologies if this question was already asked, but all questions I saw that were similar did not seem to pertain enough to what I'm trying to do to work for my program.

Comment: You should have a look at regex.

Comment: brute force search is probably fine :) how many english words are there anyway, like 800?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking for all words that have the letter "a" check for all words that have an 'a' in the second position. You can use `string.charAt(1) == 'a'` to accomplish this.

You could write a method that checks an array for letters and returns an `ArrayList` with all of the words like this.

```
public static List<String> getWords(String[] words, char c, int position) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>;
    for (String s : words) {
        if (position > s.length - 1)
            continue;
        if (s.charAt(position) == c)
            result.add(s);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Better to make your return type as `List<String>`. Nice addition of making sure you are within your string boundaries to avoid exceptions, never thought about that.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options. I have tried to showcase several of those. You will notice that I have used some Java 8 specific concepts, specifically Stream's and Lambda's. Streams will allow you to handle bigger data sets because of the possibility to parallelize your word matching.

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Play {
  static class Method {
    private Predicate<String> method; 
    private String name;
    Method(String name,Predicate<String> method) {
      this.name = name;
      this.method = method;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] words = {"axe","bow","car","eye","fat","pig","sun","bla"};
    Method [] methods = new Method [] {
      new Method("Method 1",(s)->s.matches(".a.")),
      new Method("Method 2",(s)->s.charAt(1)=='a'),
      new Method("Method 3",(s)->s.indexOf('a')==1),
      new Method("Method 4",(s)->s.matches(".{1}a.*")),
      new Method("Method 5",(s)->s.substring(1,2).equals("a")),
      new Method("Method 6",(s)->s.substring(1).startsWith("a")),
      new Method("Method 7",(s)->s.startsWith("a", 1)),
    };
    Stream.of(methods).forEach((method)->{
      System.out.append(method.name).println(":");
      Stream.of(words).filter(method.method).forEach(System.out::println);
    });
  }
}
```

If you have picked one of the option, you can easily put it in a method as follows:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Play {
  public static List<String> getWords(String[] words, char c, int position) {
    return Stream.of(words)
            .filter((s)->position < s.length())
            .filter((s)->s.charAt(position)==c)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> matches = getWords(
      new String [] {"axe","bow","car","eye","fat","pig","sun","bla","a"},'a',1
    );
    matches.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be iterating and checking for character:

```
// String[] candidateWords is your list of words,
// int targetIndex, is the index you want to check (i.e. 2)
// char targetChar, is the character you want in that position (i.e. a)

for(int i=0; i < candidateWords.length; i++)
    if(candidateWords[i].charAt(targetIndex-1) == targetChar){
       //do something (print/store word ecc..)
    }
```